# Multiple Pi Zeros over USB-Ethernet: is there a limit?

Tags: networking, usb, pi-4, ethernet, pi-zero

I want to connect 10 Pi Zeros via Ethernet over USB to get 10 Pictures at the same time. My Host machine is a Raspberry Pi 4 4GB running Ubuntu 21.04.

I got everything running as I want to with 7 Zeros connected. Once i connect the 8th Zero all Zeros are disconnectiong and connecting over and over again plus I cannot use mouse or keyboard anymore.

It seems that the Pi 4 is running out of Memory/ RAM/ something else. Is there a way to give the USB Ports more "Power" so i can connect 10?
Increasing the `usbfs_memory_mb` from the standard "16" to "1028" or even "2056" isn't solving the problem.

Comment: consider a powered USB hub?

Comment: is this necessary? i am powering all zeros seperately. but i will give it a try thanks

Comment: oh, sorry ... I didn't realise you were powering them separately - I read "Is there a way to give the USB Ports more "Power"" - and I assumed so many wrong things with that one statement

Comment: ah ok thanks! Next time i'll try to provide a clearer question

Comment: The other way to connect is using USB-to-Etherent adapters and using network switch. That should eliminate your USB hub limitations.

Comment: thanks! Do you think a way could also be to do the Ethernet part over GPIO ports?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out this Instructable: https://www.instructables.com/Multiple-Raspberry-PI-3D-Scanner/

He initially connected 40 Pis together using Ethernet to perform body scanning.

In a update (Step 8)  he increased the count up to 90 Pis tied together:
[image: 90 Pi Scanning Booth]